# How do I return the css property of a clicked div class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a color switcher where the color of a div changes based on which circle of color you clicked. I have 9 divs with class "color-circle" of various colors, how do I make it so that when the div is clicked it would return that specific "background" value?

I tried using "this" but its not working, is there a way to do this without having to write a click function for every div?

Thanks

```js
$(".color-circle").click(function(){
    $("#color-cont").css("background-color", $(this).css("background"));                    
   })
```

```css
#colorPicker {

  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.color-circle {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #DDC79B;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #C7DD9B;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #9BDD9B;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #9BDDC7;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: #9BC7DD;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(6) {
  background: #9B9BDD;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(7) {
  background: #C79BDD;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(8) {
  background: #DD9BC7;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(9) {
  background: #DD9B9B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="color-cont">
      <h3>Choose the theme color for your profile</h3>
      <div id="colorPicker">
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `background-color` and `background` do not match up. Pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".color-circle").click(function(){
   var background= $(this).css("background-color");
$("#colorPicker").css("background-color",background);                  
   })
```

First of all, you should get the `background-color` of the clicked `.color-circle`:  `var background= $(this).css("background-color");`

Then you affect this color to the `#colorPicker` div:

```
$("#colorPicker").css("background-color",background);
```

Demo:

```js
$(".color-circle").click(function(){
var background= $(this).css("background-color");
$("#colorPicker").css("background-color",background);
                      
   })
```

```css
#colorPicker {

  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.color-circle {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #DDC79B;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #C7DD9B;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #9BDD9B;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #9BDDC7;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: #9BC7DD;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(6) {
  background: #9B9BDD;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(7) {
  background: #C79BDD;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(8) {
  background: #DD9BC7;
}

.color-circle:nth-of-type(9) {
  background: #DD9B9B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="color-cont">
      <h3>Choose the theme color for your profile</h3>
      <div id="colorPicker">
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
        <div class="color-circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. Sorry was busy with uni stuff and forgot about this.